# ¿Como guardar datos en una QList en QT?

Tags: c++, qt

Yo tengo un proyecto de un estacionamiento. Tengo una complicación al momento de asignar un espacio que corresponde a un piso. No se como generar una lista con datos que tengo en mi base de datos. Cuento con la clase piso y la clase espacio ¿Me podrían da alguna idea de como hacerlo? Me dijeron que podía hacer una lista normal y compararla con los datos que tengo en mi base pero no se que tan conveniente sea.

Adjunto foto de mi base.

[image: Base de datos]

Comment: Si no pones algo de código que nos ponga en situación y nos muestre dónde tienes problemas va a estar dificil darte una respuesta

Comment: Parece que tienes un [problema XY](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3360/qu%c3%a9-es-el-problema-xy) ya que preguntas sobre una posible solucion(añadir algo a una lista) en vez de preguntar sobre el problema(alguna manipulacion con la información almacenada en una base de datos)